# Kali Linux won't boot into GUI after update

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux

I just installed Kali Linux onto my Raspberry Pi 4 B, and everything was working fine, but the I did `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` in the terminal. After that when I rebooted the GUI stopped working, I tried reinstalling the desktop environment, I tried reinstalling the graphics manager, but nothing worked. I'm not sure what happened, it might be of graphic driver issues but I'm not sure. By the way, I already tried reinstalling kali, but it does the same thing when I try to upgrade.

**EDIT**:

It turns out it's a **driver issue**, in the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` file, the log says the **`/dev/dri/card0`** file doesn't exist. Not really sure what to do.

Comment: @Ipor Sircer  --- Please feel obligated to provide a better answer than fixing Kali (which is what I tried to do)

Comment: If you have GRUB as your boot loader, can you go and check the advanced options to check if you still have the old kernel? If so try to boot that one, GUI should work.

Comment: Please add your answer in the answer section, not in the question.

Answer (score -1):

ok after days of finding a solution I figured the problem is the lightdm, so what I did is reinstalled kali from new and held lightdm packages from upgrading with the command **sudo apt-mark hold "packageName"** and then i update / upgrade. I got all my upgrades but ignored the lightdm. I think its best option for now.

Answer (score -2):

Well, if your Kali Linux installation does not boot into the GUI after an update then there are a few ways to resolve this issue which are listed below:

1. You can check the graphics driver and can update the system.
2. You can also reinstall the desktop environment.
   And before doinf this you also need to back up all required data.
   Thanks